# Webpack Dev Server scss doesn't work as intended

Tags: webpack, server, webpack-dev-server

I'm dealing with a certain problem. I'm trying to add the main.scss file and the main.js file in the entry, but the issue is that when I add both of them at once, the styles don't work as they should. JavaScript works as it should, but if I remove main.js from the entry and leave only the styles, then the styles work as they should.

If I have both at the same time, the styles don't get applied when I save the file; they only get applied to the page after I save the JavaScript file.

This is my webpack file

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        styles: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/scss/main/main.scss"),
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js/main.js"),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dev"),
        filename: "[name].js",
    },
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.resolve(__dirname, "dev"),
        },
        port: 3000,
        open: true,
        compress: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: "babel-loader",
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        { 
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
        },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "template.html",
        }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "main.css",
        }),
    ],
};
```